# DataFrame内の特定の文字列を含む箇所だけ変換したい

Tags: python, pandas

タイトルの通り、DataFrame内の特定の文字列を含む箇所だけ変換したいと思っております。
以下の画像のデータ例にある「<」を含む箇所の数値だけを変換したいです。
変換は「<」を取り除くのに加えて型変換を行い（strからfloatに変換）、「<」があった箇所のみ半分の値（1/2）にしたいと考えています。
`.str.contains('<')`といった形で指定しようとは思っているのですが、うまく`str.strip()`などと組み合わせる方法がわかりません。
同じ範囲を選択したまま処理することは可能でしょうか？

何度か繰り返すことになるので、関数として作成しようかと思っています。

[image: データ例]

現在のコード↓

```
file="～.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file)
data1 = data.drop(0,axis=0) #Remove DESCRIPTION
data1 = data1['Au*'].str.strip('<')
```

ご助力いただけませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どれだけ効率が変わるかはちょっとわかりませんが、以下のようにすると、やりたいことはできそうです。

```py
import pandas as pd


s = pd.Series({'GH101': '0.2', 'GH102': '<0.02', 'GH103': '<0.02'})
s

df = s.to_frame('value')
print(df)
print('---')

df = df.assign(
    fixed=df['value'],
    small=df['value'].str.contains('^<'),
)
print(df)
print('---')

df.loc[df['small'], 'fixed'] = pd.to_numeric(df[df['small']]['value'].str.replace('<', '')) / 2
print(df)
print('---')

print(df[['value', 'fixed']])
```

出力

```
       value
GH101    0.2
GH102  <0.02
GH103  <0.02
---
       value  fixed  small
GH101    0.2    0.2  False
GH102  <0.02  <0.02   True
GH103  <0.02  <0.02   True
---
       value fixed  small
GH101    0.2   0.2  False
GH102  <0.02  0.01   True
GH103  <0.02  0.01   True
---
       value fixed
GH101    0.2   0.2
GH102  <0.02  0.01
GH103  <0.02  0.01
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。繰り返すために少しばかり改変しましたが、うまく行きました！私の書いたコードだと中身を１つ１つ見ていくので処理時間がそこそこ長く効率の悪いコードでした。こちらを使うことでだいぶ早くなりました

Answer (score 0):

`.str.replace` でいかがでしょうか。

```
.str.replace('<', '')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。もし`.str.replace('<', '')`を使用するならば、イメージとしては`.str.replace('<', '<を取り除いた後の数値を半分')`というような変換をしたいと思っています。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
DataFrame全体ではなく、1つ1つの中身をifで判別して、該当する箇所だけ置換および半分にする処理をしました。

他に良い方法があるようなら回答お待ちしております。

```
for i in range(1,len(data1["Au*"])+1):
    if "<" in data1.loc[i,"Au*"]:
        data1.loc[i,"Au*"]=float(data1.loc[i,"Au*"].replace('<',''))/2
    else:
        data1.loc[i,"Au*"]=float(data1.loc[i,"Au*"])
```